# holoviews doesn't display PIL image format

Tags: mnist, holoviews

I am trying to import the MNIST data set and just display it using Holoviews.  When I run the following:

```
import holoviews as hv
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

hv.extension('bokeh')

mnist_images = datasets.MNIST('data', train=True, download=True)

image_list = []
for k, (image, label) in enumerate(mnist_images):
    if k >= 18:
        break
    image.show()
    bounds = (0,0,1,1)
    temp = hv.Image(image, bounds=bounds)
    image_list.append(temp)

layout = hv.Layout(image_list).cols(2)
layout
```

I get the following error at the line with 'temp = hv.Image(...)':

```
holoviews.core.data.interface.DataError: None of the available storage backends were able to support the supplied data format.
```

The 'image' variable is the following object: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=28x28 at 0x7F7F28567910>
and `image.show()` renders the image correctly.  Also if I use matplotlib's `.imshow()` I can get a correct render.

What I want is to see the image rendered in Holoviews and I expected the Holoviews.Image() would do that.  Is that not a correct assumption?  If it is, then what is wrong with the code/approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HoloViews works with numerical arrays rather than images, so `hv.Image` is for constructing an image out of a 2D array, not for showing things that are already images. But you can get numerical arrays out of PIL objects, e.g. `hv.RGB(np.array(image), bounds=bounds)` to display it as an RGB image or something similar to pull out just the grayscale values to pass to `hv.Image`.

Comment: Tnx!  hv.Image(np.array(image), bounds=bounds) was the resolution.  I had assumed PIL object was already an array ... yeah, 'Read the docs!'.